# Can't use List<String> when implementing CustomListAdapter android

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I have a collection of animal objects that are in a polymorphic hierarchy (ie Animal > Reptile > Snake). I want to create a List view where each item in the list is inflated with a different layout depending on the object type (eg one item layout for reptiles, one for cats, one for primates, etc). This activity is just the categories, not the actual list of animals. So I just want to create a "group" item.

To do this, I'm trying to just use a list of all of the possible types of animals (again, reptile, primate, cat, etc). in the form of a List collection. How can I use a CustomListAdapter to accomplish this? It doesn't seem to want to let me give the adapter a List of Strings, it wants a List of Objects.

Comment: If you are creating list of objects why would you want a list of string to be populated in adapter ??

Comment: @MezzyDroid I'm not sure I understand your question..?

Comment: I just want the first activity to have a list of the possible types. then when you click one of the items you go to the next activity, which shows all of the animals of the selected type. Also, on the list of types, I want to use a different layout for each item depending on what type it is (eg one layout file for the cat item, another for the reptile item, etc).

Comment: Another way of putting this I guess is I want to inflate a different layout resource for each item, depending on the type of item being added to the list. hope that helps.

Comment: Just make a switch statement in your adapter's oncreateView and inflate the layout by checking the type of animal

Comment: onCreateView or getView?

Comment: See my updated answer below  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the type by using switch or if statement and inflate accordingly:

Here is a sample code:

```
  @Override 
    public View getView()
    {
        View row = null;
            if (activity.equalsIgnoreCase("Ni_activity") || activity.equalsIgnoreCase("Current_NI_Activity") || activity.equalsIgnoreCase("Ni_Test_Activity")) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ni_spinner_row, parent, false);
            } else if (activity.equalsIgnoreCase("RFTestActivity")) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
            } else if (activity.equalsIgnoreCase("SiteInfoFragment") || activity.equalsIgnoreCase("LayerInfoFragment")) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.site_frag_spinner, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tvCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
            tvCategory.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            try {
                tvCategory.setText(data.get(position));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return row;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the direction I was attempting to go in, so thanks for validating my thinking and pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: done, wanted to confirm I had it in working order first. Thanks again!